# Non-existent URLs in Views 3 in drupal 7

Tags: views

I have created a page via views in Drupal 7. For example my page that is created via view is: http://www.example.com/staff. It's working correct.
When I put http://www.example.com/staff/dfasf it's also showing same data. But not going on *page not found*.

Comment: That's the expected behaviour - Drupal automatically routes you to the 'parent' if it can't find the 'child' part of the URL

Comment: can we show "page not found" for http://www.example.com/staff/dfasf this url?

Comment: Maybe set a contextual filter with 404 behaviour? Not sure, it's not something I've needed to work out how to do before

Comment: Could you rephrase your post in a form of a question? You described behavior, but didn't actually *ask* anything, so it's a bit hard to really *answer*.