# Removing duplicate content caused by node/nid/talk pages

Tags: uri

Recently I installed the talk module, didn't like it and uninstalled it.  After removing it I have noticed that I have duplicate content listed under both the node ID and the node id followed by talk.

For instance:  The page www.mysite.com/about-us is duplicated at the address www.mysite.com/node/4/talk as are all my pages.

In the talk.module file (which has been removed along with the entire talk module) I notice the line:

> $items['node/%node/talk'] = array(

To me this looks like the line of code that created these talk pages, however being that I have removed the entire module, flushed caches etc. I do not understand how these pages still exist.  Any help would really be appreciated as I have been working on this now for several days with no answer.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So `/node/4` is your about page isn't it? you just added a url alias. Which means you can access the same page with `/node/4` or with `/about-us`

To quote Clive from [Non-existent URLs in Views 3 in drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173523/non-existent-urls-in-views-3-in-drupal-7)

> That's the expected behaviour - Drupal automatically routes you to the
>   'parent' if it can't find the 'child' part of the URL

when I go to `mywebsite.com/node/1/talk` it displays the `/node/1` content to me; even though, the url in the web browser says `mywebsite.com/node/1/talk`, and I haven't even installed the talk module at all.

Try going to `mywebsite.com/node/4/ijustmadethisup` and you'll see you get displayed `/node/4`

Therefore, this is just the default Drupal behaviour, nothing to do with the talk module.

Comment: Wouldn't this be bad for SEO as someone could just build a bunch of links to non-existent pages and a search engine would see it as duplicate content?  Is there anyway to change this default drupal behavior to just throw a 404 for these pages?

Comment: I don't know why anyone would ever create links of non-existent pages. The odds of that is extremely low, I wouldn't even worry about that. I've never bothered to explore on how to change that behaviour, I can't help you with that part. Perhaps you should create a new question regarding that, if you really want to per sue that path.